# Is there a way to detect route changes with a resource?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, cross-browser, url-routing, detect

I am utilizing an ember resources as part of my application routing. I use *deactivate* on most of my routes to detect when it is changing, but can't seem to get it to work in my controller or view files. I have only seen success with *deactivate* when placing it in my route files. Is there a better way to go about this?

My main problem is that I need to detect when the page or route changes after another button and subsequent function have been called. The user process is as follows:

1. User navigates to page (which is a resource route)
2. User clicks a button to activate a feature
3. User navigates away from current page
   *Need to detect that change and hide the activated feature*

Comment: whats the problem with `deactivate`? you can have a property `active` in your controller that your view is bound to, set that to false on `deactivate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an `active` property on the controller that your button is bound to.

```
//yourcontroller.js
App.Yourcontroller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  active: true
});

// template
{{#if active}}
  <button>
{{/if}}
```

And change that value on the route's deactivate

```
// route.js
deactivate: function() {
  this.controllerFor('yourcontroller').set('active', false);
}
```

Comment: Only issue here is that I don't have a route.js file because the page is using resource so, as far as I know, can't use deactivate. Would it work to just use that function in the controller as well?

Comment: resources have routes too. ie: `this.resource('post')` would have a corresponding `PostRoute`